# Android Using a 2D array in a simple ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arrays, 2d, android-arrayadapter

I have data saved into a 2d array and want to output everything inside the column, how would I go about this?
This is what I have so far.

```
 private ArrayList[][] placeList = new ArrayList[8][9];
```

This is the loop:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                for(int x= 0; x <= 7; x++){
                    placeList[x][loops] = new ArrayList();
                }
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                placeList[0][loops].add(jo.getString("id"));
                placeList[1][loops].add(jo.getString("BusinessName"));
                placeList[2][loops].add(jo.getString("AddressLine1"));
                placeList[3][loops].add(jo.getString("AddressLine2"));
                placeList[4][loops].add(jo.getString("AddressLine3"));
                placeList[5][loops].add(jo.getString("PostCode"));
                placeList[6][loops].add(jo.getString("RatingValue"));
                placeList[7][loops].add(jo.getString("RatingDate"));
                loops++;
            }
        }
```

This is my trying to put every Business name into the the arrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtHeading , placeList[1][1 to 9]);
```

I have tried to do a loop but it will only output the last bit of data into the array.

Comment: This isn't really clear, you want just one column from your `placeList` matrix to be the source of the data in your adapter?

Comment: I want every bit of information that is saved to placeList[1].

Comment: private ArrayList[][] placeList = new ArrayList[8][9];

Comment: To start with, it looks like you can just use `i` instead of `loops` in your for loop.

Comment: Fixed that cheers, I still have the main problem though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should actually be using `ArrayList<String>`.

I think you probably want something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> placeList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
    row.add(jo.getString("id"));
    row.add(jo.getString("BusinessName"));
    row.add(jo.getString("AddressLine1"));
    row.add(jo.getString("AddressLine2"));
    row.add(jo.getString("AddressLine3"));
    row.add(jo.getString("PostCode"));
    row.add(jo.getString("RatingValue"));
    row.add(jo.getString("RatingDate"));

    placeList.add(row);
}

ArrayList<String> businessArray = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < placeList.size(); i++) {
    businessArray.add(placeList.get(i).get(1));
}

ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtHeading , businessArray);
```